# Is it possible to have multiple dependency resolvers in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection

Is it possible to have more than one dependency resolver in ASP.NET MVC 3 (similar to the case of ModelBinders and Providers)?

Comment: why do you need more than one?

Comment: I would like to have one global, other for a Controller factory, other for a Metadata Provider, and another for a Validator Provider. My guess is that could be a little bit more efficient to have one dependency resolver for each task, rather than having a single one that manages al the dependencies in a project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is one scenario that I could think of where having multiple 'containers' or 'resolvers' is useful and that is multi-tenancy. With multi tenancy you run multiple customers (organizations, with their own set of users) in the same web application, and dynamically switch based on the login, request info, or domain info.

Still, `DependencyResolver.Current` is -as Darin noted- static, so there's nothing you can (or should do about this). However, you could hide multiple containers behind a single `IDependencyResolver` abstraction and return an implementation based on some criteria. It might look like this:

```
public class MultiTenantDependencyResolver 
    : IDependencyResolver
{
    Func<int> tenantIdSelector,;
    IDictionary<int, IDependencyResolver> tenantResolvers;

    public MultiTenantDependencyResolver(
        Func<int> tenantIdSelector,
        IDictionary<int, IDependencyResolver> tenantResolvers)
    {
        this.tenantIdSelector = tenantIdSelector;
        this.tenantResolvers= tenantResolvers;
    }

    private IDependencyResolver CurrentResolver
    { 
        get { return this.tenantResolvers[tenantIdSelector()]; }
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.CurrentResolver.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.CurrentResolver.GetAllInstances(serviceType);
    }
}
```

The following code snippet shows the usage of this `MultiTenantDependencyResolver`:

```
var tenantResolvers = new Dictionary<int, IDependencyResolver>
{
    { Tenants.AbcId, BuildResolver(RegisterForTenantAbc) },
    { Tenants.KlmId, BuildResolver(RegisterForTenantKlm) },
    { Tenants.XyzId, BuildResolver(RegisterForTenantXyz) },
};

var multiTenantResolver = new MultiTenantResolver(
    () => GetTenantIdFromUrl(), tenantResolvers);

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(multiTenantResolver);


private static int GetTenantIdFromUrl()
{
    // TODO: return tenant id
}

private static IDependencyResolver BuildResolver(
    Action<IKernel> tenantSpecificRegistrations)
{
    var kernel = new Kernel();

    // TODO: Tenant agnostic registrations. For instance
    kernel.Bind<ITimeProvider>().To<SystemTimeProvider>();

    tenantSpecificRegistrations(kernel);

    return new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
}

private static void RegisterForTenantAbc(IKernel kernel)
{
    // TODO: regisrations for ABC tenant. For instance
    kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<AbcTenantLogger>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I like the approach you propose. Also, it can make very transparent to get the proper resolver for each situation.

Comment: So if you have 100k tenants (think github) you'll have 100k dependency resolvers?! I'm working on a multi tenant app right now and one resolver is enough. It simply makes no sense to have more than one. Btw, GetTenantId method should be a http module and not a static method

Comment: No no no! Tenant != user. Multi-renant apps would typically serve up to a dozen tenants. You would only do this when you have to programmatically differentiate between individual renants. Havin 100k kernels would be extremely bad for memory and performance.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have more than one dependency resolver in ASP.NET
>   MVC 3 (similar to the case of ModelBinders and Providers)?

No, this isn't possible. The [`DependencyResolver.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dependencyresolver.current.aspx) is a static property that could be assigned only one resolver. This being said having more than one dependency resolver in an application hardly makes any sense. The idea is that all your dependencies are managed by a dependency injection framework such as Unity, Ninject or StructureMap. You would then have a custom dependency resolver wrapping your DI framework of choice that will be used by ASP.NET MVC to inject dependencies in various objects of the execution pipeline.

You are comparing it with model binders in your question but this comparison is unfair because a model binder is related to a specific type that it is designed to bind. Basically you could have many custom model binders for multiple view models.

You also seem to have mentioned some *providers* in your question but unfortunately you haven't beeen very specific so it's a bit harder to comment on this one.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I guess it's unfair to make a comparson with the model binders and providers.