# MVC Dependency resolver conditional

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I am using dependency resolver and i have added my unity container to the same. So by default "GoldCustomer" gets injected in to the "CustomerController" as per the current container rules.

```
IUnityContainer oContainer = new UnityContainer();
oContainer.RegisterType<ICustomer, GoldCustomer>(); // injects GoldCustomer
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(oContainer));
```

If i want to change by current container configuration i can always create new Container and set it and call the SetResolver again. I know that the above code should be configurable via XML config  but still if we need to pickup new container objects we have to still call the setresolver.

Is this the right way or are there better ways of changing container depedency rules while the application running.

Second what are the events where we can change the container is it session_start , httphandler's  or something better.

Comment: I think this answers it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842827/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-dependency-resolvers-in-asp-net-mvc-3 

Its a static object so changing resolver is not a good idea. Must be Resolve using different conditions would be better.

Comment: I'm not understanding the use case, but maybe you want to use [container hierarchies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507462.aspx) instead?  You could set the resolver as `UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver` and only have one root container and then child containers that get automatically created by this resolver can be populated on-the-fly?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly why would you need multiple containers? It must be the singleton object who keeps all the dependency registered since the application started.

In a practice I would say keep single container and if required create multiple Registration function in separate assemblies and invoke all of them in a AppBootstrapper.

If it's an application then best way is to use the Application start with Async behaviour so that the startup doesn't get affected.

======================================================

Unfortunately the Named registration is the only option and Unity required to register with names explicitly. Thats why I personally like DI containers like Autofac and SimpleInjector. They are fast and They allow multiple registrations of an Interface with multiple Types and the resolver uses Type resolver and Named resolver methods without explicitly asking for Names and those resolvers are overridable too.

Comment: Yes i understand we can make it singleton but my situation is for one user it one set of object's injected and for other user it is some different set of objects injected.

So should i keep calling depdency resolver with different containers , assume they are already coming from some singleton factory.

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(oContainer));

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it does not look that complex to me , If I understand question quickly I can do it as follows,

assume that I have interface IMovieRepository and two classes implementing it  EnglishMovieRepository and HindiMovieRepository.

How about resolving them as in UnityConfig.cs as follows,

```
    If(condition)
    {
         container.RegisterType<IMovieRepository, EnglishMovieRepository>();
    }
   else
   {
      container.RegisterType<IMovieRepository, HindiMovieRepository>();
   }
```

If requirement is something different then  please let me know

Thanks 
/dj

Comment: This is not a valid answer because registration in Asp.Net occurs when the application start. The condition could be depending of something that is defined at runtime as mentioned in the question the type of customer. The condition needs to be done not in the registration type but at the resolving time.